# html form inputs array PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem with my cloned form:

The form has 4 inputs and I need to separate the variables and put them together by people.

My inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="fName[]">
<input type="text" name="lName[]">
<input type="number" name="age[]">
<input type="text" name="city[]">
```

My PHP:

```
$fNameArray = $_POST['fName'];
$lNameArray = $_POST['lName'];
$ageArray = $_POST['age'];
$cityArray = $_POST['city'];
```

I really do not understand how two-dimensional arrays work, to group people to complete the form, as in the following example:

> first name: siddharta, last name: naranjo, age: 29, city: mexico
>   first name: xxxxx, last name: xxxxxx, age: xx, city: xxxx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of these answers are wrong if I understand you.
First of all if you use the naming convention `data[]fname` then it will not group surely?

Secondly, the blank bracket will have it constantly move to a new array.
You will end up with a load of arrays with one element in them.

You will need to number or ID the arrays to keep them together.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        $results = $_POST['data'];
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($results);
        echo "<pre>";
    }
?>


<form action="" method="post">
    <!-- User 1 -->
    <input type="text" name="data[0][fName]" value="test 1">
    <input type="text" name="data[0][lName]" value="test 1">
    <input type="number" name="data[0][age]" value="21">
    <input type="text" name="data[0][city]" value="test 1">

    <br>

    <!-- User 2 -->
    <input type="text" name="data[1][fName]" value="test 2">
    <input type="text" name="data[1][lName]" value="test 2">
    <input type="number" name="data[1][age]" value="22">
    <input type="text" name="data[1][city]" value="test 2">

    <br>

    <!-- User 3 -->
    <input type="text" name="data[2][fName]" value="test 3">
    <input type="text" name="data[2][lName]" value="test 3">
    <input type="number" name="data[2][age]" value="23">
    <input type="text" name="data[2][city]" value="test 3">

    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

This produces this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fName] => test 1
            [lName] => test 1
            [age] => 21
            [city] => test 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fName] => test 2
            [lName] => test 2
            [age] => 22
            [city] => test 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fName] => test 3
            [lName] => test 3
            [age] => 23
            [city] => test 3
        )

)
```

Which is what it looks like you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your html is ok

If i understand you right take a look at this

```
<?php
   if($_POST && isset($_POST['fName'])) {
      $people = count($_POST['fName']);
      for($i=0; $i<$people; $i++) {
          echo "<p>first name: {$_POST['fName'][$i]}, last name: {$_POST['lName'][$i]} ...</p>";
      }
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use keys for 2 dimensional array.

```
 <input type="text" name="fName[0]">
 <input type="text" name="lName[0]">
 <input type="number" name="age[0]">
 <input type="text" name="city[0]">

 <input type="text" name="fName[1]">
 <input type="text" name="lName[1]">
 <input type="number" name="age[1]">
 <input type="text" name="city[1]">
```